# registering multiple hotkeys in application using RegisterHotKey

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm setting up multiple hotkeys in my application using registerHotKey

```
Win32.RegisterHotKey(hWndSource.Handle, add, Win32.MOD_CONTROL | Win32.MOD_SHIFT, Win32.VK_KEY_D);
Win32.RegisterHotKey(hWndSource.Handle, manage, Win32.MOD_CONTROL | Win32.MOD_SHIFT, Win32.VK_KEY_M);
```

This is all find and dandy, but I'm confused with how I am supposed to catch each one.  Here is the proc that occurs when a hotkey is pressed:

```
 private IntPtr MainWindowProcCatchManageHotkey(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case Win32.WM_HOTKEY:
                if (wParam == (IntPtr)(-16285))
                {
                    CaptureManageHotkey();
                }
                if (wParam == (IntPtr)(-16303))
                {
                    CaptureSelection();
                }
                handled = true;
                break;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

This is pretty ghetto. It works from the little I've tested it, but I'm not willing to push it without a better understanding of what is happening. The only reason I know what values to test wParam against is because I ran the debugger and set a breakpoint so I could see what was being passed into the function. Is there somewhere I can look up the values for lParam and wParam in my case? I want to catch ctrl+shift+d for one, and ctrl+shift+m for another. Where can I see what the lParam and wParam for those should be?

tl;dr How can I know what values of lParam and wParam I want to look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wParam` values are the `id` values you passed when you called `RegisterHotKey`. In this case they are the values `add` and `manage`.

The `lParam` value contains the key combination that was actually pressed.

> The low-order word specifies the keys that were to be pressed in combination with the key specified by the high-order word to generate the `WM_HOTKEY` message.

It's all explained in the MSDN topic for [`WM_HOTKEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279.aspx).

Comment: This worked! As I suspected, when I switched computers and began running the code again, the values for wParam in my original post changed.  Using 'add' and 'manage' worked on both computers though!